# Looking for online material by previous Chief Rabbis of the UK

Tags: rabbis, internet

I'm trying to find online material (essays, sermons, articles, etc.) to read by previous [Chief Rabbis of the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chief_Rabbis_of_the_United_Hebrew_Congregations) before Rabbi Jonathan Sacks. I am particularly interested in [Joseph Hertz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Hertz), [Israel Brodie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Brodie) and [Immanuel Jakobovits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Jakobovits,_Baron_Jakobovits). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems a little broad. Consider asking about the different rabbis separately.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say "**any** help", here is a small offering:

Part of “Immanuel Jakobovits: A Coherent Theology of Apparent Contradiction” is available [here](https://academic.oup.com/mj/article-abstract/30/2/127/1030178/Immanuel-Jakobovits-A-Coherent-Theology-of) – more if you have an Oxford Academic account .

Answer (score 1):

From Joseph Hertz there is a great selection of papers and sermons [here](https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Hertz%2C%20Joseph%20H.%20%28Joseph%20Herman%29%2C%201872-1946%22).